# Ensembles crash in CDERebaser.m

Tags: ensembles

In Ensembles, I'm getting a crash at this line in CDERebaser.m in the method "rebaseWithCompletion":

```
BOOL passedChecks = [revisionManager checkRebasingPrerequisitesForEvents:eventsToMerge error:&error];
```

The crash is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I've had Ensembles working in production on the store for a few months with no issue at all until now. This crash just started randomly occurring. No updates to the app were made.

Any ideas?

** UPDATE **

Stepping through it, it seems to fail in this conditional statement in CDERevisionManager.m:

```
    if (![self checkContinuityOfStoreModificationEvents:eventsWithBaseline]) {
        methodError = [NSError errorWithDomain:CDEErrorDomain code:CDEErrorCodeDiscontinuousRevisions userInfo:nil];
        result = NO;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version? Many of those error memory bugs have been fixed. They were due to changes on autorelease pools in Core Data

Comment: I am using version 1.6.1. I updated through CocoaPods and I believe that is the latest.

Comment: I've made some changes that I hope fix the issue. Difficult to test. I have pushed them to the master branch, but there is no release yet. You should be able to test by referencing the master branch directly on GitHub with Cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I still get the same crash. I tried updating Ensembles with Cocoapods using this line:    pod 'Ensembles', :git => 'https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles.git', :branch => 'master'.  Is that the way you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. Not sure what could cause the crash then. If you can isolate it more, let me know. Using zombies may help.

Comment: Here is the zombie:  http://i63.tinypic.com/160soqf.png  Unfortunately I couldn't get Ensembles to symbolicate in Instruments. Let me know if I can provide anything more to help.

Comment: Looking at the zombie, I suspect Cocoapods did not make use of the latest master branch. You probably need to configure it to do that. I guess it will get the latest release tag otherwise. (The reason I can see that is that the new code does not call the `errorWithDomain:` method anymore.)

Comment: To verify, I did a comparison using FileMerge between CDERevisionManager.m in my project and the one on GitHub (with an edit date of 23 Jan) and it shows 0 differences, but I still get this zombie:  "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'NSError' object (zombie) at address: 0x170a5cd10." Any ideas I can do to pinpoint it further?

Comment: Not sure what is happening then, I'm afraid. If you look at that commit, the `[NSError errorWithDomain...` calls are removed (https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles/commit/3bac90a11b6c489e1f95cdc945f4094dbefd51ea). So I don't see how they would appear in the zombie traceback unless something has gone wrong getting the latest code.